# How to create navigation bar with Login | Sign Up button in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, navigation, bootstrap-4

I want to create a navigation bar with Login | Sign Up button in **bootstrap 4**. kindly check the image what I am looking for exactly:

[image: Desktop Version]

[image: Mobile Version]

Kindly Check my code what I am doing:

navigation.php

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Using the exactly above code I am getting below output:
[image]

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong. Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: You're using Bootstrap 3 markup for Bootstrap 4. [Read the docs for the correct Bootstrap 4 Navbar structure](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no glyphicons in BS 4, you have to use Font Awesome. Since BS 4 has flexbox included, you align elements with `ml-auto` (align-right) and `mr-auto` (align-left).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span> Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (see it in full page):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">First Page</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled Page</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```